# Unable to put "X" to right prompt to indicate number of jobs in Zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt, job-control

This [article's](http://www.miek.nl/blog/archives/2008/02/20/my_zsh_prompt_setup/index.html) code does not work for me. I have pasted all its code to my .zshrc.

I have the following in my `.zshrc`

```
RPROMPT='%{\[0;33m%}%1v%{\[0m%}'
```

It should indicate whether you have jobs or not. However, it does not do that for me.

I would like to get an X to the right prompt to indicate that you have a job running.

**How can you have a right prompt which shows X if you have more than one jobs in Zsh?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you're using won't work because it's trying to use the `$psvar` variable, which you haven't set. Probably that article mentioned it somewhere else.

Anyway, to display the number of jobs in the `RPROMPT`, use

```
$> RPROMPT="%j Job(s)"
```

To have it display an 'X' if you have at least one job running, use

```
$> RPROMPT="%1(j.X.)"
```

Look under the PROMPT section of the `zshmisc` manpage, or take a link: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/ . It explains all the expansion sequences that you can use to display information in your prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! -- I have now the following in my .zshrc: RPROMPT=$(echo '%{\033[32m%}%~ %1(j.%j.)'). Is there any way to write the same shorter? I tried without echo unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing extra left brackets from from your ANSI escape sequences, plus I don't think `\[` is doing what you expect.

Here's what you want:

```
RPROMPT="%(1j.%{^[[33m%} X%{^[[0m%}.)"
```

However, you may find it more useful for the prompt to show *how many* jobs are in the background:

```
RPROMPT="%(1j.%{^[[33m%} (%j jobs)%{^[[0m%}.)"
```

**Note**: Those `^[` above are literal escape characters — e.g., `0x1B`. On the command line (or in Vim's insert mode if you're using Vim to edit your `.zshrc`) type Control-V then Control-[ to insert an escape character.